# How to access dynamically loaded child class from its parent class in c#?

Tags: c#

I have created a new class library project to create a TaskClass which is inherited from my Parent class BuildDataToo l(Added as a reference). I'm loading this new class from dll using `Assembly.LoadFrom` in my BuildDataTool's solution. I'm using reflection to get all the child of BuildDataTool using

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BDTTask)).GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BDTTask)));
```

But I'm not getting the dynamically loaded child. How do I get it?

Comment: All children from...that assembly, not all loaded assemblies.

Comment: There are some classes present in BuildDataTool Project which is found through the above code. I'm loading other assemblies in this project dynamically but they can't be seen through above code.

Comment: Yeah, if you call GetTypes on one assembly then  you get only types from that assembly. Cycle through all loaded assemblies in current AppDomain

Comment: Done! Thanks man.